# Article with "connection"

Tags: articles

I have the following sentence:

> Overfitting is meant to be a situation when the learned model has too strong **a connection** with the training set which can negatively affect accuracy in a new dataset.

I was given advice about using an article with "too strong a connection" but I am not sure about it. What do you think; should it be there?

Comment: The article?  It sounds fine to me.  I'd add a comma after training set, since which introduces a non-restrict relative clause.

Comment: Is it possible to add an article with too? I have never seen it before.

Comment: *Too + adjective + a/an + vowel* is idiomatic. I have *too small a nose* to play the title character in the play 'Cyrano de Bergerac'.

Comment: What advice were you given?